# Mouseover created object (vba)

Tags: forms, vba, excel, userform, mousemove

Well, I'm not a pro in programming, so I've been working on a vba code awhile, and at this time I've put some *Label objects* 'manually' on a *Form*, by calling *Me.Controls.Add* function, setting new *label* config (autosize, width, pos etc...), to which *Caption* is assigned the *Value* of a cell from the *ActiveWorkBook*.

Ok until that. But now I'd like to use *MouseMove* effect on these new created labels, and I couldn't.

One more thing: this *Userform*, let's call it *Userform X*,  initializes from a first *Userform Y* window, where in this Y userform I click on a button to load and show *Userform X.*

So *userform X* creates all labels when initializing, before showing itself up.

I presume there's a way to 'reload' eighter 'refresh' *userform X* and it will understand as the created labels had always been there and I'd be able to *MouseMove* over them. But How?

Here is this part of the code:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        On Error Resume Next
        c = 0  'counting for labels name

        'Open source workbook 

        If Not IsWorkBookOpen.IsWorkBookOpen("Book.xlsm") Then
            Application.Workbooks.Open "Book.xlsm", , True
        End If
        Workbooks("Book.xlsm").Sheets(1).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate

        'Do the Addlabel 

        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
            If ActiveCell.Value <> "Price" Then
                addLabel
                c = c + 1
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Loop

        'Close source workbook
        Workbooks("Badges.xlsm").Close False 
    End Sub

Private Sub addLabel()
Dim theLabel As Object

Set theLabel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Procedimentos_Label" & c + 1, True)
With theLabel
    .AutoSize = True
    .Caption = ActiveCell.Value
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 100
    .Top = 100 + 20 * c
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Here's a Microsoft link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/userform-mousemove-and-click-events-with-label/68431181-43e0-4eb9-89aa-61721265e6a4